# Нажатие на кнопку OK в VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Есть такое задание:

> Пользователь вводит 15 произвольных чисел на Лист3. Программа находит квадраты введённых чисел и выводит их в диалоговом окне. Программа прекратит работу, если вместо ввода нажать ОК.

Возникли проблемы с нажатием на кнопку ОК, не понимаю, как реализовать это код

```
Sub Задание_3()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 15
    nR = InputBox("Введите число " & i)
    If nR = "" Then
        MsgBox "Поле не может быть пустым!"
    Else
        MsgBox "Квадрат введеного числа: " & nR * nR
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: InputBox в принципе не позволяет различить, что именно было нажато - кнопка или Enter. Сделай свою форму ввода - это самое простое имхо...

Comment: *Программа прекратит работу, если вместо ввода нажать ОК.* Нажать ГДЕ? в поле ввода или в MsgBox, показывающем результат?